# Getting a list of subclasses of a reference class

Tags: r, reference-class

I created an `AbstractFoo` reference class and several subclasses, now I want to get all the names of the subclasses (`AFoo`, `BFoo`, `CFoo`). It seems this is possible using the `subclasses` slot of an S4 class, but I'd like to get the same sort of thing for a reference class.

For instance my code might be:

```
AbstractFoo <- setRefClass("AbstractFoo")
AFoo <- setRefClass("AFoo", contains = c("AbstractFoo"))
BFoo <- setRefClass("BFoo", contains = c("AbstractFoo"))
CFoo <- setRefClass("CFoo", contains = c("AbstractFoo"))
```

So I would want something that returns `c("AFoo", "BFoo", "CFoo")`.

Comment: Can you give an example of `AbstractFoo`

Comment: @d.b I added an example in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foo = function(nm){
    objs = ls(envir = .GlobalEnv)
    tmp = setNames(lapply(objs, function(objName){
        thisObj = get(objName)
        if (class(thisObj) == "refObjectGenerator" & objName != nm){
            is(thisObj(), nm)
        }
    }), objs)
    tmp = unlist(tmp)
    names(tmp)[tmp]
}

foo("AbstractFoo")
#[1] "AFoo" "BFoo" "CFoo"
```